# Can we develop a talent to draw engineering drawings in Auto CAD without having the knowledge of making engineering drawings on paper

Tags: education, autocad

My question is can I refer and learn AutoCAD such that I can teach it to some engineering students, while I'm not a Engineering graduate?

I mean, I'm a Mathematics graduate, who has a good knowledge in computer science though. So, I feel that I can easily learn AutoCAD. But I'm not sure whether I'll be able to give good examples for Engineering students because so far I don't have any knowledge in Engineering drawings they usually do on "on paper".

Will I be able to use only a basic knowledge on Engineering drawings and do AutoCAD for them, while still not having a complete knowledge about Engineering drawings done on "on paper"?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I'm sorry, but CAD design/technical drawing is generally off-topic here.  This site is about graphic design.  Also we can't really speculate about your abilities. You know your own abilities better than any other person.

Comment: For more information about what topics you can ask about here, please check the [help page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The answer is: No, you can not. Its not so much about generating a drawing as its about understanding the manufacturing methods used, strength, tolerancing and conventions of different branches. Being able to draw something is just the start of the journey. Validating the design and getting it made is the game. Students generally become good at making drawings after 4 years of practice even though they can have a drawing done first day of class. Also autocad is prettymuch the legacy application, only really used by civil engineers at this point. And even they are trying to deprecate it.

Comment: Technical drawing is additionally a skill akin to writing or legal contract making (because that is what they often are). Yes kids can write, but do they write easy to read, understandable, error free, misunderstanding free, concise and well structured texts that are easy to maintain and track changes in.

Comment: So the fastest way to understand technical drawings is to go and make a flanged bushing with a internal groove for a snap ring on a manual engine lathe. This will instantly impart appreciation of a drawings structure, and need for seeing things you can not see in reality, Ans once you are done you get appreciation of tolerance stack ups.

Comment: I feel something is missing here. If I want to create an engineering drawing to be read by *humans*, I use pen and paper. If I want to create a design to be read by *machines* (e.g. a laser-cutter), I would use CAD software. Who is going to read your drawings?

Comment: @Hermann why would you choose pen & paper for an engineering drawing for humans? A sketch, yes, but a proper drawing with dimensions etc.?  AutoCAD and other traditional CAD software was developed for human-readable drawings; integration with CAM was a logical progression.

Comment: ... Now I design one-offs in Inventor as 3d models.  My milled parts get converted to a CAM format in a semi-automated fashion, similarly for 3d printing.  My turned parts are made by hand from a drawing because we don;t have a CNC lathe.  But for all parts I still produce a drawing, even if it only needs to be fully dimensioned for turning.

Comment: @ChrisH If the overall goal is to teach someone to create an engineering drawing, then I start with pen and paper. It completely removes the "how to use this particular software". We can focus on "what needs to be communicated so the part can be manufactured *by someone else*". Using CAD software is the next step because it dramatically increases design speed, especially for complex parts. However, working with a higher speed will not be beneficiary for a student if they do not know what they are doing.

Comment: @Hermann *Teaching* is another matter.  Teaching the goal rather than the tool is great, even if it's not something to be rushed.  But you mentioned creating a drawing, not teaching.

Comment: … However, the overall goal could be teaching to produce a design for a lasercutter or 3D printer or maybe even a CNC mill. You can totally operate a 3D printer without being able to create conventional engineering drawings at all. I consider that a different skill.

Answer (score 8):

So I will answer this since we have this exact situation unfold in front of us. So turns out that our workshop floor has a bottleneck issue. This bottleneck is caused by students not being able to generate suitable quality of technical drawings/3d models. So our operator/teachers need to spend extraordinary amounts of time debugging, sending work back to be redone and negotiating with students to get them to minimum level of competency. The primary responsible teachers are generally unable to help.

This results in 7 x 100-200€ an hour machines standing half idle, when the work is spent in doing things that ought to have been done by the designer. Now its not like these students haven't been taught to use their CAD application. Its just that they have too little time on making designs and understanding the implications of what they have done.

Since all of the people who could help here are already allocated to even more important tasks the solution that management came up with is that we teach one of our computer savvy computer scientists to the task. Well its not entirely that simple, we have now reserved 2 hours of 3 persons time every week to bring the persons up to speed by next 4-8 months. Technically it was supposed to be 4 but the first candidate burned out in the process. (which is not surprising engineering students have 4 hours every week for 2 semesters and even they still aren't entirely ready to make drawings up to scratch).

So generally I would say no you can not do this. But its not entirely impossible it requires how much resources you have. I mean we expect our new member to be laser/ waterjet/surface cutting/3d printing daily next 4 months to get there and eventually design for 5 axis machining, casting, press die making and deep drawing. But then you may not need exactly that much out of your drawings but the engineers will at some point.

Was i personally ready? Hell no, I had 2000 manhours of training and even my first and second practical design was only semi passable.

Comment: PS: make something, design a card board box, then manufacture it with your drawings. Did it work right? Laser cut pieces and join them together.....

Comment: Yes, it's not the drawings but the thought processes behind them that need to be learnt. I had no formal training but had the good fortune to spend a few years as a systems design engineer working with some old-fashioned draughtsmen.  Even the less grumpy one didn't take it well if I made the same dumb mistake twice.  So I learnt about designing things that could be made.  Of course the other half of the lesson is respecting your experts, discussing the tricky bits early.  The software just makes it possible to turn a decent design into a decent drawing with modest skill - and bad into bad

Answer (score 5):

Software is a **tool**. Knowing a **tool** *never* translates to acumen in a given profession.

Where software is concerned...

##### The *how* is easy. It's a simple matter to teach...

- This button does X
- This menu item does Y
- This command does Z

X, Y, and Z all generate relatively similar results. They are merely alternative methods in the software to go from A to B. Heck, for the "*how*", much of the time, it's possible to merely use the software user's manual and/or documentation as a pseudo-syllabus.

##### The *why* is *never* easy.

It's a *completely different* matter to teach **when** to use X, Y, or Z.

- When is X more appropriate than Z
- When will Y will cause more issues than it may momentarily resolve
- When is Z blatantly incorrect

**None** of this can be taught without first an understanding of the profession and *how* the software is utilized within the profession.

One needs to have a grasp of **real-world usage** in order to effectively, and efficiently, teach any tool (software) for a *career track*. It's one thing to teach a course for some specific software, it's entirely different to teach a course for a professional track which *may* utilize some application.

I believe, it's a disservice to teach others if you don't understand the profession beyond its tools. One may be able to teach the *tool*, but not the tool as its used in a given *profession*.

Comment: I would like to add here that while it may seem that knowing a trick will enable you to do a task X easily. But you can not become a robust worker by knowing a bunch of  disparate tricks. The basic tooling is usually really boring to learn. Also different professions have separate tools, i can instantly spot a competent mechanical designer in the way they layout their sketches so that they are design meaningful. And a woodworker from the way they plan the grains of their material and how to minimize waste. Not because its the simplest way to do the shape but because its the sane way to do it.

Comment: That somewhat translates to most software @joojaa -- I can instantly tell the proficiency of a designer merely by seeing an InDesign layout, or a PSD/AI file. Well-honed professionals tend to do things in very similar ways - regardless of when or where they were trained - because they know what works well or is the most appropriate configuration for production.

Answer (score 0):

As a mechanical engineering student I feel I can give a valid opinion here. It is most certainly possible to learn engineering drawing without doing it on paper. My university in Germany actually teaches it directly for Solidworks without bothering about paper drafting.
But the real issue that you might face is your lack of experience with manufacturing techniques, lack of knowledge about standards (such as DIN norms, standardized parts) and such. A lot of the standards relevant to engineering drawing can be found in this book: https://www.europa-lehrmittel.de/Mechanical-and-Metal-Trades-Handbook/1910X-4
If you are able to gain experience by observing and interacting with technicians and machine operators, you might just be able to bridge this gap.
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very very much @KarthickAshwath are there any qualifications like Diplomas, that we can do in a short time period, which will give a qualification for us to be a teacher in engineering drawing (now I'm asking about drawing on papers)?

Comment: Perhaps like a certificate from an accredited institute, which will make me qualified to teach engineering drawing? I'm not an engineering graduate nor an engineer.